# How to fetch fields or schema of a FaunaDB class

Tags: faunadb

Is it possible to fetch FaunaDB class schema or fields through fauna-shell or fauna-java API?

I am expecting fields and it datatypes for a given class or instance

Answer (score 6):

Fauna doesn't have schema enforcement baked into it, so the only way to know what fields are present on a particular class instance is to fetch that instance and inspect it. [You can find example queries for loading instances in the FaunaDB documentation.](https://app.fauna.com/documentation/howto/crud)

You can also run a query like (excuse my JavaScript, it would look slightly different in Java.) `q.Paginate(q.Indexes())` -- this will list all the indexes in a database. And `q.Paginate(q.Classes())` will list the classes. A query like `q.Get(q.Class("greetings"))` will load a particular classes schema, for indexes it looks like: `q.Get(q.Index("all_greetings"))`